# Correcting a text if it is not a number

Tags: python, function, input, while-loop, calculator

I am building a basic calculator using python and I have a feature that will detect if the text entered is a number or not. For that I have defined a function ie

```
def check_num(num):
    while not num.isnumeric():
        print("Invalid number! Please enter a valid number.") 
        num = input()
```

When I take an input of the number it is taking just the first input.

```
num1 = input()
check_num(num1)
```

How do I make it take the correct input that is the last input?

Here is an image of the code running in command prompt:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to change your function definition, so that the function returns `num`:

```
def check_num(num):
    while not num.isnumeric():
        print("Invalid number! Please enter a valid number.") 
        num = input()
    return num
```

and then call it like this:

```
num1 = check_num(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a recursive function that asks for the number instead of simply checking it:

```py
def ask_num():
    num = input()
    if num.is_numeric():
        return num
    print("Invalid number! Please enter a valid number.") 
    return ask_num()
```